# Как лучше реализовать доступ к одинаковым данным в реальном времени

Tags: rabbitmq, big-data, apache-kafka, messaging

Добрый день. Есть десяток скриптов, на разных серверах, которые ежеминутно генерируют файл динамичный по содержанию, но примерно одинаковый по структуре. 
Структура файла не стандартная (не XML, Json), но данные структурированы.
Файлы весят от 1мб до 5мб
Нужно все эти файлы консолидировать в одной системе и отдавать по запросу другим (целый зоопарк) с возможность брать только те данные, которые необходимы.
Систему, генерирующую эти файлы трогать нельзя (legacy прямиком из мезозоя)
Данные нужно как-то хранить в течении суток. 
Сейчас все передается файлами в кучу программ с помощью ESB(не устраивает скорость и отказоустойчивость).

В связи с этим вопрос с помощью чего это лучше всего реализовать?

Я предполагаю следующую цепочку: **Сервер с файлом -> Сервис прослойка на каждом сервере (для трансформации файла и общением с Kafka)-> Kafka -> Система клиент**

Но возможно я не понимаю, как работает Kafka и можно ли это реализовать на нем?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) для чтения файла, возможно, [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) для предварительного парсинга и передачи в кафку.